# Suppose $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sqrt{n-a_{n-1}}$ $\forall n \in\mathbb{Z_{\ge 2}}$. What is the least integer $n$ for which $a_n>4$? ⌊$a_{100}$⌋?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, nested-radicals

Suppose $a_1=1$ and $a_n=\sqrt{n-a_{n-1}}$ $\forall n \in\mathbb{Z_{\ge 2}}$. What is the least integer $n$ for which $a_n>4$? What is $\left \lfloor a_{100} \right \rfloor$, where $\left \lfloor u \right \rfloor$ is the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $u$?

---

As an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio), the $n^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number can be found without finding the preceding $(n-1)$ numbers.

---

I am not sure if we can solve my problem efficiently, easily, and without a calculator.

---

Using a computer calculator, I found that

$\sqrt{19-\sqrt{18-\sqrt{17-\sqrt{\cdots-1}}}}<4$ and $\sqrt{20-\sqrt{19-\sqrt{18-\sqrt{17-\sqrt{\cdots-1}}}}}>4$

---

If we can not solve this easily without a calculator, then can we just get an upper limit and a lower limit "*good guesses*"?

Here, "*good guesses*" like when we try to find $\sqrt[3]{50}$, we know that $3^3=27$ and $4^3=64$, therefore, $\sqrt[3]{50}$ is a value between $3$ and $4$. So, to get a good approximation, we do not need to look at any value $\notin (3,4)$.

---

I am interested in finding an explicit method rather than guessing.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

**Your second question**

- It's easy to see that $\forall n \geqslant 2 \ , \ a_n \leqslant \sqrt{n}\ $ . So $a_{100} < \sqrt{100} = 10$ and $a_{99} < \sqrt{99} < 10 $.
- Then $\ \ a_{100} = \sqrt{100 -a_{99}} > \sqrt{100-10} > 9 \ $ .
- So  $\ \fbox{$\ \left\lfloor a_{100} \right\rfloor = 9\ $}\ $ .

**Your first question**

- $\forall n \geqslant 2 \ , \ a_n<\sqrt{n}$
- $\forall n \geqslant 3 \ , \ a_n=\sqrt{n-a_{n-1}}>\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-1}}$
- $\forall n \geqslant 4 \ , \ a_n=\sqrt{n-a_{n-1}}>\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-1-\sqrt{n-2}}}$
- $\forall n \geqslant 5 \ , \ a_n=\sqrt{n-a_{n-1}}>\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-1-\sqrt{n-2-\sqrt{n-3}}}}$
- We can show that $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is increasing.
- $a_{19} < \sqrt{19-\sqrt{18-\sqrt{17}}} < 4$
- $a_{20} > \sqrt{20-\sqrt{19-\sqrt{18-\sqrt{17}}}} >4$